# How to detect when the remote peer has disabled the track in WebRTC?

Tags: javascript, webrtc

I am writing a WebRTC app where peers can pause/resume sending media data by calling:

```
function pause() {
  sender.replaceTrack(null);
}
function resume() {
  sender.replaceTrack(track);
}
```

Is there a *native* way (other than using the signaling server) to detect when a remote peer has paused/resumed sending media data?

I tried to add handler to `'mute'` and `'unmute'` events on the received track but nothing happens (except `onunmute` got called once). I inspected the tracks in the browser dev tools, and got `{ muted: false, enabled: true }` on the `RTCRtpReceiver.track` event when the other peer's `RTCRtpSender.track` is `null`.

Comment: Not as far as i know, you will have to use the signaling server. You could use some other software to check if the frames are all black.

Comment: I do not think it is possible to check if stream was `muted` by a peer, but it is possible to measure audio volume / energy (either via `AudioWorklet` or via `RTCRtpReceiver.getStats`).
If you want to have a strict and 100% accurate check you could try to open webrtc data channel and use it for sending any meta information about the call.